# Altering table row colors trought multirow

Tags: tables, multirow, rowcolor

I can alternate the color of the rows in a table with `\rowcolors`. However, when I use `\multirow` it makes breaks the 'logical coherency':

**How it works:**

[image: How it works]

**How should it works:**

[image: How should it works]

**MWE for the first output:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\rowcolors{1}{green!15}{green!25}
\begin{tabular}{rr}
T   &   d \\
400 &   -   $\pm$   -   \\
500 &   -   $\pm$   -   \\
600 &   -   $\pm$   -   \\
750 &   237 $\pm$   30  \\
    &   60,000          \\
\multirow{-2}{*}{1000}  &           $\pm$20,000 \\
750 &   500 $\pm$   30  \\
500 &   250 $\pm$   10  \\

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I know how to produce the second output by using `\rowcolor` in each line (at least after the multiple row), but I am wondering is there a way to make it automaticly (like `\multirows` replaces `\rowcolor` in each line when I don't use `\multirow`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or do it with `makecell`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{table}
        \rowcolors{1}{green!15}{green!25}
        \begin{tabular}{rr}
            T   &   d \\
            400 &   -   $\pm$   -   \\
            500 &   -   $\pm$   -   \\
            600 &   -   $\pm$   -   \\
            750 &   237 $\pm$   30  \\
            1000  & \makecell[r]{60,000\\$\pm$20,000} \\
            750 &   500 $\pm$   30  \\
            500 &   250 $\pm$   10  \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

With the help of the `nicematrix` package and the `repect-blocks` option of its `\rowcolors` command:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{NiceTabular}{rr}[code-before =\rowcolors{1}{green!15}{green!25}[respect-blocks]]
T                    &   d               \\
400                  &   -   $\pm$   -   \\
500                  &   -   $\pm$   -   \\
600                  &   -   $\pm$   -   \\
750                  &   237 $\pm$   30  \\
\Block{2-1}{1000}    &   60,000          \\
                     &   $\pm$20,000     \\
750                  &   500 $\pm$   30  \\
500                  &   250 $\pm$   10  \\
 
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```